# SCIM API Filtering Users on meta.LastModifiedDate

Tags: scim

I am using following filter with "Beyond Insight" SCIM API users endpoint,

BaseURL/v2/Users?filter=meta.lastModified le "2011-05-13T04:42:34Z"

I am getting "search field is invalid: meta.lastModified". What could be the reason ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SCIM service providers are not obligated to support filtering on all attributes. The baseline is typically userName, emails and externalId. Are you sure that this SCIM service provider supports filtering on meta.lastModified?

Also - assuming your URL is just a typo above, but it would be /Users?filter=, not /Users/filter=

Comment: Thanks. URL, was a typo. I did not find anything on service provider's site which confirms whether they support filtering on meta.lastModified.

Comment: Given the response I'd be inclined to think they don't support filtering on that attribute, then.